# How to best load CSV data into a Apache Spark dataframe from my own Java Stream?

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In service implemented in Java (I don't know Scala) I consume Zstd compressed CSV data (base64 encoded after compression) from an AWS SQS queue (up to 256 KB at a time before compression, typically a few megabytes each after decompression). Ideally I would have liked to use something like structured Spark streaming to perform queries on the streaming data as well as on the growing collected dataset but as I read the documentation I cant use this with my own custom protocol/collection logic.

Instead I am looking at periodically create new "micro batch" data frames from the collected CSV data and "union" with a "aggregation frame" that I query.

I have managed to do this if I first store the resulting CSV data to a file that I then load using Sparks built in CSV support and a schema I have defined that also states the desired data types to use. Sadly this slows down my ingestion too much (the SSD disk becomes a bottleneck) so I would like to do it only using RAM.

To do this I am feeding the messages into a sequence of Java streams that first BASE64 decodes and then decompresses.

My question is if I can use the Spark built in CSV import with this Stream, i.e. I do not find a way to use DataStreamReader with an already created io Stream rather than specifying a file name.

So far I have not found a way to do this and as a work around have tried using my own CSV parsing library, building JavaRDDs of Rows but this became quite complex (seems like I need to create the right type of Java objects according to the Schema i.e. Long, Integer, String etc. or the data frame will not be correctly created from in my next step), memory consuming and slow so I would have prefered using the built in code that already exists and is performant and reliable if I just could figure out how...

All suggestions are warmly appreciated!